# Reference precreated jQuery dialog based on selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

I create a jQuery dialog in the usual way, `$('#MyDlg').dialog(...)`, and display it. In some other function I want to close it, so I do `$('#MyDlg').dialog('close')`, but nothing happens.

After some testing I found that if I save the object reference from dialog creation, make it available to the other function, and call `dialog('close')` on it, the dialog does close as expected.

Isn't is supposed to work the way I tried first? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your first snippet is supposed to work. Do you perchance have more than one element with a `MyDlg` id attribute?

Comment: Aha! You're right! The problem is that the dialog DIV is rebuilt in the original DOM location by an Ajax call, so the other function picks up that "un-dialogified" DIV rather than the first one. I'll have to rethink my logic/layout... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was pointed in the right direction by Frédéric Hamidis comment. The dialog DIV is rebuilt in the original DOM location by an Ajax call, so the other function picks up that "un-dialogified" DIV rather than the first one. I end up with a DOM containing two DIVs with the same id. Not good.

I will relocate the dialog div to a part of the layout that does not get rebuilt.